# prove that a 1-form on the torus $T^2$ is closed, without computing its differential

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I'm given he following closed form on $\Bbb R^2$ $$\omega = (\sin^4\pi x+\sin^2\pi(x+y))dx - \cos^2\pi(x+y)dy$$

and let $\eta$ be the **unique** $1$-form on the torus such that $p^*\eta=\omega$, where $p$ is the usual covering $\Bbb R^2\to T^2$.

> Show whether $\eta$ is closed/exact or no.

I showed that $\eta$ is not exact since there is a loop s.t. $\int_C \eta \neq 0$. But I've no idea how to deal with closeness. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is p? Also why not computethe differential?

Comment: $p$ is the universal covering map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $T^2$. and concerning the differential, well you don't have an explicit expression for $\eta$ so don't know which differential you want to compute

Comment: Notice that $p^*$ is an isomorphism and $d\omega = dp^*\eta = p^* d\eta$. So if we know that $d\omega = 0$ then this implies $d\eta = 0$ as well. Now you may write $$ \omega = \sin^4 (\pi x) \, dx - dy + \sin^2 \pi(x+y) \, d(x+y) $$ to show that $\omega$ is closed.

Comment: @SangchulLee could you please elaborate on the fact that the map $p^*$ induces an isomorphism?

Comment: Its injectiveness follows from the fact $p$ is a local diffeomorphism. I don't think it's surjective, but you don't need that.

Comment: @Pedro thanks, I was aware of being injective (just forgot that) but I didn't know it was surjective as well, so I was quite confused

Comment: @Pedro : I challenge that this map is injective. Maybe we are talking about different maps (since p wasnt specified), but I assume to be p just the quotient map. But then different points in R^2 get mapped to the same point on the torus.

Comment: @lalala Pedro claimed that $p$ is a local diffeo (which is true, being a covering map, *the usual covering map*  from $\Bbb R^2$ on the torus. Using that you prove that $p^*$ is injective, **not** $p$